# java.lang.NullPointerException: the servlet is never executed?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, tomcat, servlets

I'm learning how to do a maven dynamic web application with Eclipse and Tomcat. The applicacion works without servlet, but I get that error when I try to introduce it in my code. I debugged to find the problem. I think, these are the relevant points:

1. To be able to deploy a war file, I added to maven the dependency "servlet-api" **with provided scope** as suggested here: 
   [How to compile a servlet for Tomcat in command line? error: package javax.servlet does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104937/how-to-compile-a-servlet-for-tomcat-in-command-line-error-package-javax-servle)
2. The error is in MostrarLibros.jsp. If I use the the next code without servlet, everything works:

   ```
   listaDeLibros = Libro.buscarTodos();
   ```

   But if I change that line to the one provided below, the exception appears. Actually, the variable "listaDeCategorias" is null after running it (I debugged it):

   ```
   listaDeCategorias = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("listaDeCategorias");
   ```
3. I add a break point in the Servlet, ControladorLibros.java, but the debugger never stops there. Code:

   ```
   package com.arquitecturajava;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.List;
   import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   public class ControladorLibros extends HttpServlet {
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
               HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
           RequestDispatcher despachador = null;
           if (request.getServletPath().equals("/MostrarLibros.do")) {
               List<Libro> listaDeLibros = Libro.buscarTodos();
               List<String> listaDeCategorias = Libro.buscarTodasLasCategorias();
               request.setAttribute("listaDeLibros", listaDeLibros);
               request.setAttribute("listaDeCategorias", listaDeCategorias);
               despachador = request.getRequestDispatcher("MostrarLibros.jsp");
           } else if ...

           (...)

           request.setAttribute("listaDeLibros", listaDeLibros);
               request.setAttribute("listaDeCategorias", listaDeCategorias);
               despachador =    request.
                       getRequestDispatcher("MostrarLibros.jsp");
           }
           despachador.forward(request, response);
       }
   }
   ```

4 - web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ControladorLibros</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ControladorLibros</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.arquitecturajava.ControladorLibros</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ControladorLibros</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

5 - Project structure:

[image: project structure inside Eclipse]

Is it because the servlet isn't found by the application? In this case, why isn't found?

Comment: If the debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoint, this is an indication that your application is running on an older version of your code. Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: there's also a setting that turns off all breakpoints, though

Comment: Given the fact there's a big IF in the servlet, you'd put a breakpoint in both cases.

Comment: Just check if you didn't use this option by accident http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116260/enable-and-disable-all-breakpoints-in-eclipse

Comment: Does anything change if you use prefix/suffix/fixed mapping instead of declaring servlet as a default one?

Comment: stupid question, but are you actually debugging the app or did you just place a breakpoint. Is the debugger running and connected to the server instance?

Comment: Sotirios, DigCamara, and eis: I also added a breakpoint in MostrarLibros.jsp. The debugger stops there but not in the servlet. 
I clean and redeploy with Maven. No luck.

Comment: @Alfabravo: I put the breakpoint at the first if. It should stop there!

Comment: @skuntsel: I don't understand. You want that I change <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> to something, right?

Comment: UPDATE: I updated the point 2 of my question to make it clearer.