# Breakpoints in Eclipse stopped working

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

I was coding late yesterday (might be important) and debugging and breakpoints were working fine.

Today, probably when I pressed some unknown shortcut, execution is not stopping on breakpoint.

First thing I noticed is strange icon:

[image]

but I found no option (basically because I do not know what I'm looking for) to switch it back...

Currently it is crossed (I do not know what is that) but it is not disabled (icon is empty in such cases).

Comment: You have 'Skip All Breakpoints' selected - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4116260/2670892

Comment: Maybe you are running, not debugging it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable breakpoints.
Click `Windows > Open perspective > Other` Choose `Debug`.

Refer screen-shot

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Also you can assign key board short cut to `Skip All Break Points` command in `Windows > Preferences > Keys`.

Comment: No, I do not want to use it, thanks. I just do not know, how I turned it on yesterday (there is no default shortcut).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screenshot,  it seems your break points are skipped.  You should be able to enable them from the debug perspective. 
Look for a blue circle with a line across it. Should say skip all breakpoints (if memory serves me right)