# Enable and disable all breakpoints for one of many active debug configs in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Rather than disabling breakpoints for all debug configs, it'd be nice to disable breakpoints for one particular running debug config.

For my case, there's common code between a client and server. I'd like to only enable breakpoints for the server, so that I don't have to relaunch the client with debugging disabled.

I'm looking for finer granularity than that in [Enable and disable all breakpoints in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116260/enable-and-disable-all-breakpoints-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be creating breakpoint working sets and then using 'Group by' to show them by working set. That would allow to easily enable/disable breakpoints.
Multiple selections of existing breakpoints can be moved to a working set with drag and drop (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Add VM argument `-Dbrk=A`, `-Dbrk=B`... into Eclipse run / debug / server configuration.
2. Add [conditional breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7194409/2158271) with condition `"A".equals(System.getProperty("brk"))`, `"B".equals(System.getProperty("brk"))` ...